# How to efficiently call setState on both cases - succes and error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm using `react` and I have an asynchronous action that receives some data from API using `axios`. I also have a flag (state variable `tableLoaded`) which describes if data is fetched.

```js
this.props.fetchDataAction(requestParams).then(
  () => {
    this.setState({
      data: this.props.reports.data
    });
  }
).then(() => {
  this.setState({ tableLoaded: true })
});
```

I want my flag `tableLoaded` to be set to true in both cases - either after API call succeded and failed, so I just added another `then()` on my Promise, which triggers function that sets this flag to true.

My question is - is this the best solution to achieve my goal? Or should I repeat this code in both cases?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [Promise.finally](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/finally) syntax.

```
this.props.fetchDataAction(requestParams)
.then(() => {
    // Do your thing on success
    this.setState({
        data: this.props.reports.data
    });
})
.catch((error) => {
    // Do something if failed
})
.finally(() => {
    // Do this in all cases..
    this.setState({ tableLoaded: true })
});
```

**Edit:**
If the return from `fetchDataAction` is an Axios promise, then you should replace `.finally` by `.then` because Axios doesn't offer the `finally` method. I would then say that your original suggestion was correct. You could comment the second `.then` so you know why.

```
this.props.fetchDataAction(requestParams)
.then(() => {
    // Do your thing on success
    this.setState({
        data: this.props.reports.data
    });
})
.catch((error) => {
    // Do something if failed
})
.then(() => { // Triggered in all cases by axios
    // Do this in all cases..
    this.setState({ tableLoaded: true })
});
```

Comment: `setState` is async, so `.finally()` is not always guaranteed that is updating after or before first state update.. But `setState` second callback function guarantees that it will be triggered when the first one is done.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `all()` to catch success and failures

Answer (score 0):

One issue you'll run into with the current approach is that any possible errors will prevent the last `.then` from running, making it possible for `tableLoaded` to remain `false` if something *does* go wrong. [See this pen for an example of this issue.](https://codepen.io/kingdaro/pen/OogbYL?editors=0012)

`Promise.finally` is one good way to step around this, as another answer points out, but my personal preference would be to use [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).

```
try {
  await this.props.fetchDataAction(requestParams)
  this.setState({
    data: this.props.reports.data
  })
} catch (error) {
  // handle error
}
this.setState({ tableLoaded: true })
```